# Html - contact info at the bottom

Tags: html

I want to put my contact information at the bottom of the page but the text starts covering it self.

Here is my code:

```
<div style="position: relative">
                        <h3><p style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; width:100%; text-align: center; color:white"><strong>Contact info<strong></p></h3>

                        <div class="award">
                            <p style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; width:100%; text-align: center; color:white"><strong>Gmail</strong></p>
                            <p style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; width:100%;"><img src="image link" height="20px" width="20px" border="1px"></p>
                            <ul>
                                <p> style="color:white">my emal</p>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that my bottom text (Contact info and Gmail start coverning)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the `position: fixed` to the container div, not to its children elements (and erase it from the other elements). They all have the same position now, that's why they overlap - "fixed" relates to the position in the viewport.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; width:100%;">
  <h3 style="text-align: center; color:white"><strong>Contact info</strong></h3>
  <div class="award">
    <p style="text-align: center; color:white"><strong>Gmail</strong></p>
    <p style="text-align: center;"><img src="image link" height="20px" width="20px" border="1px"></p>
    <p style="text-align:center;color:white">my email</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your fixed code? I am an beginner and it vould mean a lot.

Comment: I just added it to my answer. I also changed a few other things (superfluous tags and styles)

Comment: thenks for your help

Comment: Thanks I tryed to run the code and it worked

Comment: I have one more question do you know how can I make it so that the bottom part (Contact info) shows when you scroll down

Comment: Into what shoud I change position: fixed to?

Comment: I am realy new to this field so I vould apprechiate any help

Comment: Just erase it, then the default setting `position: static` will apply.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: **I strongly do not recomend using inline styles for things like that.** (inline styles are those that are defined in the style="" atribute) For more information read [this](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/difference-between-inline-external-and-internal-css) article.

So, your problem is that you put the fixed position property to all single elements but to the container one you added a relative position. This means that the container is relatively positioned to parental element and only the elements inside are fixed so they would stay fixed if you would scroll the container [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position). The solution would be simpy add the fixed position to the **container div**. Like that:

```
<div style="position: fixed; bottom: 0;">
                        <h3><p style="width:100%; text-align: center; color:white"><strong>Contact info<strong></p></h3>

                        <div class="award">
                            <p style="width:100%; text-align: center; color:white"><strong>Gmail</strong></p>
                            <p style="width:100%;"><img src="image link" height="20px" width="20px" border="1px"></p>
                            <ul>
                                <p> style="color:white">my email</p>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
</div>
```

But remember to do that in internal css not inline, that was just an example